# Copy large amount of files from MAC to Windows server and preserve modify and creation date

Tags: windows, macos, server, copy

I have an issue with moving a large number of files and folders from old MAS OSX server ( 10.9.4) to Windows Server 2016.

I already try to use robocopy but I always get an error - File creation error - The file or directory is not a reparse point.

The same thing happens when I am using xcopy.

I also tried to copy files from MAC to windows after mounting a share on MAC and use scp but also there are some errors and not all files are moved.

Can anyone know a way how I can copy files and preserver this creation and modified date?

Comment: rsync is an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use `tar`.

`tar` like `rsync` and `lsyncd`preserves modification times, etc.

For `tar` you would:

1. `tar` up all the files just like a backup
2. `gzip` the tar ball
3. copy the gzipped tar ball to Windows
4. Extract the files using WinRAR.  The file modification times will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

rsync works fine now but I needed to give full permission over the newtork to prevent any issues